# Perl MYSQL Error : libmysql.dll

Tags: mysql, perl, dll, libmysql

Have you ever met this error when code Perl to access db MYSQL : 
The procedure entry point mysql_get_parameters could not be located in libmysql_.dll ?

I already copied libmysql.dll from D:\xampp\mysql\lib\ to many places and renamed it to libmysql_.dll: 
- D:\xampp\perl\vendor\lib\auto\DBD\mysql\
- C:\WINDOWS\System32\
But still Entry Point Not Found -.-'

Please help ...

Regards, 
Christine

Answer (score 4):

1. Download Strawberry Perl from http://strawberryperl.com/
2. Install it on your PC
3. Find libmysql_.dll file from C:\strawberry\c\bin
4. Copy it onto D:\xampp\perl\vendor\lib\auto\DBD\mysql

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an OLD problem, but current strawberry perl (5.24.1.1) will not work as downloaded/installed unless you use the answer above to fix it.

Copy the dll located at [DRIVELETTER]:\Strawberry\c\bin\LIBMYSQL_.dll

TO: [DRIVELETTER]:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\lib\auto\DBD\mysql

And your legacy mysql scripts will work again :-) (well, mine did)

Answer (score 0):

Copying 
***C:\strawberry\c\bin\libmysql_.dll*** 
to 
***c:\strawberry\perl\vendor\lib\auto\mysql*** 
does not work in Release Strawberry 5.28.2.

My solution is rather unusual - but works (until now): 
I took the **libmysql_.dll** from **Release Perl 5.12** from **ActiveState** (yes, sorry, but I was in despair)!!! 
Copying this file (from 28th Sept 2016) to 
***c:\strawberry\perl\vendor\lib\auto\mysql*** did it for me.